# javascript url parsing with spaces and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, parsing

Can someone tell me why this script wont prefill the form if the parameter has a space or parenthesis in it. It works fine for letters, numbers and underscores, but with spaces and parenthesis it stops working. Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input name="name_f" id="name_f-0" type="text"/><br/>
  <input name="name_1" id="name_1-0" type="text"/><br/>
  <input name="email" id="email-0" type="text"/><br/>
  <input name="password" id="password" type="text"/><br/>
  <input name="contact" id="contact" type="text"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function _id(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e)
  }

  var QueryString = function() {
    // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
    // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
    var query_string = {};
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");

      // If first entry with this name
      if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
        query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
      } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
        var arr = [query_string[pair[0]], decodeURIComponent(pair[1])];
        query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
      } else {
        query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
      }
    }
    return query_string;
  }();

  if (QueryString.name(awf_first)) {
    _id('name_f-0').value = QueryString.name(awf_first);
    _id('name_1-0').value = QueryString.name(awf_last);
    _id('email-0').value = QueryString.email;
    _id('password').value = QueryString.password;
    _id('contact').value = QueryString.contact;
  }
  // QueryString.nameofparameter
  // ex: QueryString.email 
  // QueryString.password
  // QueryString.name
  // QueryString.otherparameter
  // QueryString.anothername

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any console errors? like `QueryString.name is not a function` ?

Comment: or perhaps `awf_first is not defined`

Comment: in fact, QueryString is `{"":"undefined"}` - probably nothing like you expected

Comment: It would be better to initialise *query_string* as a blank object to avoid accidental matching with a default property: `var query_string = Object.create(null)`, or include a *hasOwnProperty* test. Then, instead of `typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined"` use `pair[0] in query_string`. ;-)

Comment: Can you post a **working** example? E.g. replace ` var query = window.location.search.substring(1);` with a fixed value that causes the issue. Where are *awf_first* and *awf_last* defined?